# Sky blue dot next to app

Tags: iphone, ios

I got an iPhone 7+ on iOS 10.2 and I just got this sky blue dot next to an app, instead of the normal blue one.

As you can see in the screenshot, there's a real difference between the sky blue and the normal one

Do you guys know what that means?

Thanks

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going by memory on this answer because I can't recall at this moment the Apple Support doc that covered this (I'll have to look it up later or someone can update my answer if they have the link).

Both colors indicate that an update was performed and you haven't opened the app since that update.

The **dark blue** dot means the app was updated manually.  This means you saw an update was available and you tapped the button to perform the update.

The **light blue** dot means the app was updated automatically.  This means you have automatic updates turned on and the App Store checked, saw an available update, and updated the app without your initiating the update.

I hope that makes sense and that it's not vica-versa.

Comment: What about for light/dark orange beta application dots? Beta applications don't update automatically...

Comment: That's a separate question that I could answer separately and (hopefully) get another 20 points!  jk, I don't know about a red dot, I've only see the orange dot next to apps installed via TestFlight ([FAQ which has something about this](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/TestFlightFAQ.pdf), search for 'dot').  Maybe there's slight shade differences between combinations of backgrounds/screens/device?

Comment: Haha, yes, I was talking about the orange dot. But if your (theory?) about the blue dots is correct, that's really interesting!

Answer (score 1):

The dots are slightly transparent, so if they are in front of a dark wallpaper, they will appear darker. Try swapping the order of your Periscope and Netflix apps (or changing your wallpaper) and you'll notice that the dots for each app will change color respectively.

Comment: What's interesting is that the background under the lighter blue dot appears to be nearly as dark as that under the darker blue dot. @Arthurooooo, it would be interesting to see the same dots with a different background.

Comment: True, but it probably takes an average value of the area around the dot as well. In the original picture, the background around the Periscope app does appear to be lighter. I confirmed that the dots do change color based on the background on my iPhone running iOS 10.3